# How to server static files + proxy context

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf, mod-proxy

I am wondering how to configure my httpd server to serves the following pages:

My need is to serve static content located in my /var/www/static when url is /context/static and to proxy the remaining to a tomcat server

In this order:

```
/context/static/* --> files served by httpd
/context/*        --> resources served by tomcat
```

I have tried to rewrite /context/static/* to a folder pointing to my /var/www/static and added the `ProxyPath` directive for the remaining but I can't get it working.

What are the best practices and how to achieve that ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in fact it is quiet easy...

Having such folders configured:

```
/var/www/static/
               |-  css/*
               |-  js/*
                \  medias/*
```

The following httpd configuration will redirect static/* to the `/var/www` and the rest will be proxied

```
# first rewrite for statics
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/context/static/(.+)$ /static/$1

# then proxy remaining...
ProxyPass               /context  http://127.0.0.1:8080/context
ProxyPassReverse        /context  http://127.0.0.1:8080/context
```

Comment: I got similar case but can't make it work can u help me?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48671458/apache-2-4-proxy-css-and-js-path

Comment: It wasn't very clear in which file this had to go, I made it work inserting this code in a conf file located in the /sites-available directory, maybe it works too in .htaccess, I didn't try it.

Answer (score 3):

I've found the following approach that works and is quite general.  (4/12/2018)

Location/Proxypass expressions always take priority over any other location block, so you have to  **Exclude** the paths that you don't want to be proxied.   the "?!" does that in the regex.  Since static content is, um, static,  it is not so bad to require that the apache configuration be updated if another directory is needed to be served directly for a different media type.

The following was taken from a server that was proxying a Python Flask application.

```
<LocationMatch  "^/(?!js|css|media)" >
  ProxyPass   http://127.0.0.1:5000
  ProxyPassReverse   http://127.0.0.1:5000
</LocationMatch>

<Location "/">
  Require all granted
</Location>
```

Answer (score 1):

Both of the existing answers rely on Regular Expressions. While they work, it is possible to do this without such complicated constructs. [`ProxyPass`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) can take `"!"` as a second parameter, in which case it doesn't proxy the matching URL. For example

```
ProxyPass /context/static/ !
ProxyPass /context http://127.0.0.1:8080/context
ProxyPassReverse /context http://127.0.0.1:8080/context
```

or, with multiple exclusions,

```
ProxyPass /js !
ProxyPass /css !
ProxyPass /media !
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

These exceptions need to come before the more general rule in order to take precedence.

*Thanks to freenode user "thumbs" in #httpd.*